# Finding total number of items in multiple instances of a collection & binding count to Textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, xaml

As the title states, I am trying to find the total number of items in multiple instances of an `ObservableCollection` and bind the result to a `Textblock`. I managed to get the correct number via LINQ...

```
public WorldViewModel(GameContainer container)
{
    GlobalPopulation = container.Regions
            .SelectMany(x => x.Settlements)
            .SelectMany(x => x.Population)
            .Distinct()
            .Count();
}

public int GlobalPopulation { get; set; }
```

... but LINQ doesn't work well with XAML binding. The initial value displays properly but doesn't update as the count changes. If I create a new instance of my viewmodel, the new number displays since the constructor is being called again. My viewmodel inherits from MVVM's ViewModelBase and implements INPC via Kind of Magic. I have other properties that are bound properly and behave as expected, so that's not the issue.

I have tried using tools like OLinq and BindableLinq with no luck. Right now it's looking like I'll have to do this without LINQ, but unfortunately I don't know how to, without LINQ, retrieve the same value and bind it to the `Textblock`. If anybody could either show me a way to make the LINQ binding work in this situation or how to achieve the same result without LINQ, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: How do you change the count? To which collections and how you add items?

Comment: Currently I just have a method that adds a set amount of new people to the Population property (an ObservableCollection) of each of the Settlements when the program starts and a button bound to a command that creates a single person and adds it to one of the Population collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to forget that you can subscribe to the changes in your `ObservableCollection` yourself:

```
// not production-quality code
public WorldViewModel(GameContainer container)
{
    foreach (var region in container.Regions)
    {
        region.CollectionChanged += (s,e) => RecalculateCount(container);
        foreach(var settlement in region.Settlements)
        {
            settlement.CollectionChanged += (s,e) => RecalculateCount(container);
            foreach( var population in settlement.Population)
            {
                population.CollectionChanged += (s,e) => RecalculateCount(container);
            }        
        }
    }

    RecalculateCount();
}

private static void RecalculateCount(GameContainer container)
{
    GlobalPopulation = container.Regions
                .SelectMany(x => x.Settlements)
                .SelectMany(x => x.Population)
                .Distinct()
                .Count();
}
```

So long as `GlobalPopulation` is firing property changed events, changes to the count of settlements will be propagated to the UI.

(You'll probably want to store the `GameContainer` instance on your view model and then reference it from a non-static version of RecalculateCount, rather than capturing it in the event handling lambda; that code is intended to be a drop-in demo, but probably has strange object lifetime issues hiding in it.)

Comment: After a bit of modification, your solution works perfectly! I can't thank you enough for this. It's a shame I can only upvote it once.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
public int GlobalPopulation { get; set; }
```

to this:

```
private int _globalPopulation;
public int GlobalPopulation 
{ 
    get { return _globalPopulation; }
    set
    {
        _globalPopulation = value;
        NotifyPropertyChange("GlobalPopulation");
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you recalculate the property every time the collections change.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. Is there not a LINQ-free way to get that number and have the Textblock update as needed?

Comment: @JasonD your application has no way of knowing when the DATA in the DataBase changed. Make sure you recalculate the property everytime the collections change.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I suppose that's what I'll have to do if there isn't a more 'hands-off' way.